# How to fix solution with double integration

Tags: fortran, gfortran, fortran90, fortran95

The solution for this double integration is -0.083 but in the final compliation it appears -Infinity. It seems that the error is very simple, but I really can't find it.

I have been searching specially in the module section but I don't see why it appears like -Infinity. For example, if you change the two functions between them (x in f2 and x^2 in f1) the solution for the integration is 0.083 and the code gives it correct. Can annyone find the error? Thanks a lot.

```
module funciones

contains

function f(x,y)

implicit none

real*8:: x,y,f

f=2d0*x*y

end function

function f1(x)

real*8::x,f1

f1=x

end function


function f2(x)

real*8::x,f2

f2=x**2d0

end function

function g(x,c,d,h)

implicit none

integer::m,j

real*8::x,y,c,d,k,s,h,g

m=nint(((d-c)/h)+1d0)

k=(d-c)/dble(m)

s=0.

do j=1d0,m-1d0

y=c+dble(j)*k

s=s+f(x,y)

end do

g=k*(0.5d0*(f(x,c)+f(x,d))+s)

return

end function


subroutine trapecio(a,b,n,integral)

implicit none

integer::n,i

real*8::a,b,c,d,x,h,s,a1,a2,b1,b2,integral

h=(b-a)/dble(n)

s=0d0

do i=1d0,n-1d0

x=a+dble(i)*h

c=f1(x)

d=f2(x)

s=s+g(x,c,d,h)

end do


a1=f1(a)

a2=f2(a)

b1=f1(b)

b2=f2(b)

integral=h*(0.5d0*g(a,a1,a2,h)+0.5d0*g(b,b1,b2,h)+s)

end subroutine

end module



program main

use funciones

implicit none

integer::n,i

real*8::a,b,c,d,x,s,h,integral

print*, "introduzca los valores de a, b y n"

read(*,*) a, b, n

call trapecio (a,b,n,integral)

print*,integral

end program
```

The main program is simple, just calling the subroutine and using the module. It also prints the final result.

Comment: Welcome, please read [ask] and [mcve]. You should also include the main program so that we can test the code. Please use indentation when writing the code so that it is readable.

Comment: Thanks, I will upload the main program!

Comment: Some indentation and less empty lines would be beneficial.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new here. I am still learning how this works.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, like mentioned in the comments: your problem is not clear. Which input parameters `a`, `b` and `n` do you use and which result do you expect?

Other than that: the code you posted used deprecated features and non-standard types and bad code style.
Some general hints:

- `real*8` is non-standard Fortran. Use `real(real64)` instead. real64 has to be imported by `use :: iso_fotran_env, only: real64.`
- non-integer expressions (`do i=1d0,n-1d0`) in do-loops are a deleted feature in modern Fortran. Use integers instead.
- code should be formatted with white spaces and indentations
- `print*,` should be replaced with `write(*,*)`
- code should always use English names
- write `implicit none` in the beginning of the module, not for every function.
- make the module/program interface clear by using the statements `private`, `public`, and `only`
- if You want to convert to type `real`, use the function `REAL` instead of `DBLE`
- I prefer the cleaner function definition using `result`
- use `intent` keywords: `intent(in)` passes the variable as a const reference.
- the variables `c,d,x,s,h` in the main program are unused. Compile with warnings to detect unused variables.

This is the code changed with the suggestions I made:

```
module funciones
use :: iso_fortran_env, only: real64
implicit none

private
public :: trapecio, r8

   integer, parameter :: r8 = real64

contains
   function f(x,y) result(value)
      real(r8), intent(in) :: x,y
      real(r8) :: value

      value = 2._r8*x*y
   end function

   function f1(x) result(value)
      real(r8), intent(in) :: x
      real(r8) :: value

      value = x
   end function

   function f2(x) result(value)
      real(r8), intent(in) :: x
      real(r8) :: value

      value = x**2._r8
   end function

   function g(x,c,d,h) result(value)
      real(r8), intent(in) :: x, c, d, h
      real(r8) :: value

      real(r8) :: y, k, s
      integer :: m, j

      m = NINT(((d-c)/h)+1._r8)
      k = (d-c)/REAL(m, r8)
      s = 0._r8
      do j = 1, m-1
         y = c + REAL(j,r8)*k
         s = s + f(x,y)
      end do

      value = k*(0.5_r8*(f(x,c)+f(x,d))+s)
   end function

   subroutine trapecio(a, b, n, integral)
      real(r8), intent(in) :: a, b
      integer, intent(in) :: n
      real(r8), intent(out) :: integral

      integer :: i
      real(r8) :: c, d, x, h, s, a1, a2, b1, b2
      h = (b-a)/REAL(n,r8)
      s = 0._r8

      do i = 1, n-1
         x = a + REAL(i,r8)*h
         c = f1(x)
         d = f2(x)
         s = s + g(x,c,d,h)
      end do

      a1 = f1(a)
      a2 = f2(a)
      b1 = f1(b)
      b2 = f2(b)
      integral = h*(0.5_r8*g(a,a1,a2,h) + 0.5_r8*g(b,b1,b2,h) + s)
   end subroutine
end module

program main
   use funciones, only: trapecio, r8

   implicit none

   integer :: n,i
   real(r8) :: a,b,integral

   write(*,*) "introduzca los valores de a, b y n"
   read(*,*) a, b, n
   call trapecio (a,b,n,integral)
   write(*,*) integral
end program
```